# replace one csv values from other and fill missing ones

Tags: shell

I have two csv files. First's format is:

```
2019-10-01,1,2,3,4,5,6
2019-10-03,11,22,33,44,55,66
2019-10-05,10,20,30,40,50,60
```

Second's format is (one column):

```
2019-10-01
2019-10-02
2019-10-03
2019-10-04
2019-10-05
```

My goal is to replace second's csv lines with first one's lines if the date is the same. And after that, fill missing lines with values from above lines. Expected result:

```
2019-10-01,1,2,3,4,5,6
2019-10-02,1,2,3,4,5,6
2019-10-03,11,22,33,44,55,66
2019-10-04,11,22,33,44,55,66
2019-10-05,10,20,30,40,50,60
```

Is it approachable with sed or awk commands, or shell script is the only option?

Comment: Are the files sorted?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's *approachable with* `awk`, e. g.:

```
awk -F, '{today=$0    # if needed, get next line from first file and store the data:
          if (today>date) {getline <"First.csv"; date=$1; OFS=FS; $1=""; rest=$0}
          if (date==today) data=rest  # if date reached, recall new data
          print today""data
         }
        ' Second.csv
```